# get Elastic search data n hours back

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elastic Search query "gte:now/d" which gives the data after 00:00:00 means only todays data but when I am querying at 15:00PM as now-15h then count for both the query is different.
Please help me.

Comment: try this one now/h-15h, this should help for furthur reading https://discuss.elastic.co/t/several-date-math-questions/27453/3

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/several-date-math-questions/27453/3 this answer is probably going to help you more

Comment: I tried  now/h-15h . this is also not working

Comment: can anyone please  explain  why result differs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response but I figured out my solution.
I added "time_zone" filed and "h-15h" and got same result.
I come to know using "time_zone" filed with any date type field is a good practice.
Thanks once again.